Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@73e0fb8c marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(17008)
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    
    public void enrollStudents(List<Student> students) {
    
        //Calling 1st method (verification)
        studentRepository.performBackgroundVerification(students);
        
        //Calling 2nd method (enroll)
        studentRepository.enrollStudents(students);
    }
}

@Repository
public class StudentRepository {

    public void performBackgroundVerification(List<Student> students) throws Exception {
    
        Connection wrappedConnection = null;
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = null;
        
        try {
            
            //Get Wrapped Connection
            wrappedConnection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
                
            //Get Oracle Connection
            oracleConnection = wrappedConnection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
            
            //Create Oracle Object(typ_student_obj")
            Struct[] studentStruct = new Struct[students.size()];
            for(int i=0; i<students.size(); i++) {
                studentStruct[i] = oracleConnection.createStruct("TYP_STUDENT_OBJ", new Object[] {
                    students.get(i).getFirstName(), Date.valueOf(students.get(i).getDateOfBirth()), students.get(i).getAddress(), students.get(i).getAge()
                });
            }
            
            //Create Oracle Array(typ_student_tbl)
            Array studentStructArray = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("TYP_STUDENT_TBL", studentStruct);
            
            //Call Stored Procedure
            Map<String, Object> resultSet = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                    .withSchemaName(schemaName)
                    .withCatalogName(PackageConstants.PKG_STUDENT)
                    .withProcedureName(StoredProcedureConstants.SP_INSERT_STUDENTS)
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter[] {
                        new SqlParameter("p_student_data", OracleTypes.ARRAY),
                        new SqlOutParameter("p_status", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                    })
                    .execute();
            
            if(resultSet.get("p_status") != null) {
                String verificationStatus = String.valueOf(resultSet.get("p_status"));
            }   
        }
        finally {
        
            if(wrappedConnection != null && !wrappedConnection.isClosed()) {
                wrappedConnection.close();
                logger.info("WRAPPED CONNECTION IS CLOSED ? : "+wrappedConnection.isClosed());
            }
            
            if(oracleConnection != null && !oracleConnection.isClosed()) {
                oracleConnection.close();
                logger.info("ORACLE CONNECTIONS IS CLOSED ? : "+oracleConnection.isClosed());
            }
        }       
    }
    
    public void enrollStudents(List<Student> students) throws Exception {
    
        Connection wrappedConnection = null;
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = null;
        
        try {
            
            //Get Wrapped Connection
            wrappedConnection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
                
            //Get Oracle Connection
            oracleConnection = wrappedConnection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
            
            //Create Oracle Object(typ_student_obj")
            
            //Create Oracle Array(typ_student_tbl)
            
        }   
        finally {
        
            if(wrappedConnection != null && !wrappedConnection.isClosed()) {
                wrappedConnection.close();
                logger.info("WRAPPED CONNECTION IS CLOSED ? : "+wrappedConnection.isClosed());
            }
            
            if(oracleConnection != null && !oracleConnection.isClosed()) {
                oracleConnection.close();
                logger.info("ORACLE CONNECTIONS IS CLOSED ? : "+oracleConnection.isClosed());
            }
        }
    }
}

spring:
  application:
    name: test-jobs
  profiles:
    active: local
  datasource:
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 5
      connection-timeout: 60000
      idle-timeout: 600000  #default is 600000 i.e 10 minutes
      max-lifetime: 1800000 #default is 1800000 i.e 30 minutes
      pool-name: testPool

I am getting the below error when the studentRepository.enrollStudents(students); method is called from the service class
    2024-10-29 02:30:01.575  INFO 29665 --- [taskScheduler-2] com.karthik.util.HikariPoolUtil         : WRAPPED CONNECTION IS CLOSED ? : true
2024-10-29 02:30:01.578  INFO 29665 --- [taskScheduler-2] com.karthik.util.HikariPoolUtil         : ORACLE CONNECTIONS IS CLOSED ? : true

    2024-10-29 02:00:02.038  WARN 29665 --- [taskScheduler-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : myPool - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@73e0fb8c marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(17008)
        java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.clearWarnings(PhysicalConnection.java:2936) ~[ojdbc8-19.10.0.0.jar!/:19.10.0.0.0]
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.close(ProxyConnection.java:267) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    

My understanding is wrappedConnection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(); should return a new connection from the connection pool. Why closing the connection in the previous method throws this error.
Can you please help resolve this error?

Are you sure that you need to close the unwrapped connection? Closing the wrapped connection should return the connection to the connection pool and allow it to be re-used. Closing the unwrapped connection may be bypassing that and closing the underlying connection so that when the connection pool tries to reuse it it has already been closed.

It will not return a new connection it will return a connection from the pool. As a rule of thumb, if you are doing jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(); you are doing it wrong. Take a few steps back and rethink your solution. In your case you probably should use the JdbcTemplate.execute which takes a ConnectionCallback so that you get a connection instead of obtaining it yourself and don't have to mess around with the lifecycle. Regarding the lifecycle call close only once as that will return the connection to the pool (but you shouldn't do using the JdbcTemplate properly.

@MT0 I updated the code to close only wrapped connection. I no longer see the connection closed error. I have to check whether the connection goes back to the pool
